# Agrupación por fechas en query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

No he podido hacer otra agrupación por fecha en mi query; actualmente tengo los siguientes resultados de esta query:

```sql
SELECT Estado, Fecha ,sum(case when CODIGO_ORG IN ('AR1','AR2') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS AFORO, SUM(IMPORTE_COBRADO) AS IMPORTE
FROM TRANSITOS
WHERE id_periodo IN (127)
and id_TRANSACCION_SITUACION < 100
and ID_CAS IN(306,311)
GROUP BY Estado,Fecha 
ORDER BY Estado,Fecha;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no he podido hacer es que me agrupe y sume los aforos e importe de las fechas que son iguales; bueno, de hecho, del 21 al 30 de junio es la misma fecha, por ejemplo: del día 21 son aforos 211 + 298=509, me los coloque en una sola línea y no en dos como se ve en la imagen.

Comment: Debes definir bien el criterio de agrupación. Si bien las fechas son iguales, el estado es diferente. Si te interesa todo, quita la columna de estado y deja solo le fecha en la agrupación.

Comment: @jachguate  gracias, así justamente lo necesitaba

Comment: Excelente, ahora con más tiempo escribí una respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es definir bien el criterio de agrupación.

En este caso te está mostrando varios registros por fecha, porque los valores de la columna `estado` son diferentes.

Si quieres que sume todos los valores de una fecha, elimina la columna `estado` de la consulta y de la agrupación.

Por ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT Fecha
       , sum(case when CODIGO_ORG IN ('AR1','AR2') THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) AS AFORO
       , SUM(IMPORTE_COBRADO) AS IMPORTE
  FROM TRANSITOS
 WHERE id_periodo IN (127)
   and id_TRANSACCION_SITUACION < 100
   and ID_CAS IN(306,311)
 GROUP BY Fecha 
 ORDER BY Fecha;
```

Te va a devolver la suma de lo que actualmente obtienes en 2 filas por cada fecha. Si hubieran más estados, la consulta original te devolvería más filas y esta última una fila por cada fecha, siempre, sin importar cuantos estados haya.